# Best test to analyse percent data that are negatively skewed

Tags: mathematical-statistics, biostatistics

I have an outcome variable that is the percent of correct answers to a test. The distribution is severely skewed to the left with many observations close to 100 (as shown in the histogram below). I have a total of 380 observations, divided into 5 groups.

I would like to check for differences between the groups and adjust for age, sex and years of education.

What would be the best approach to this problem?
I thought about poisson regression but the data is limited at 100. I also thought about doing logit transformation of the outcome and then linear regression, but I'm not sure this is the right approach.

Thank you in advance[image]

Edit: After some reading, I decided to use beta regression, as @jcken suggested. As my dependent variable had a lot of 1s (100%s), I used the transformation
(y * (n−1) + 0.5) / n
where n is the sample size, as suggested in the betareg documentation in R (cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf).
Alternatively, the 0 or 1 inflated beta regression was described in 2015 and is implemented in R (cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoib/zoib.pdf).

Comment: Have you thought of/heard of Beta regression? It models the response as a beta distributed RV with parameters that depend on covaraites. For modelling in R see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf

Comment: @jcken Thank you!
I was looking at Beta regression right now and it seems like the right answer. 
I was also thinking that quasibinomial(logit) regression might fit?